# Are questions about using geogebra off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a question about using [Geogebra](http://geogebra.org/) to create a diagram that will later be included in my LaTeX document, but the question isn't directly related to LaTeX. Does that make it off-topic? If so, are there other sites which would be a better fit?

Comment: Could you please add a link for Geogebra so people can see what it is exactly? Questions about non-TeX software are usually off-topic, except if you directy ask how to insert it into LaTeX documents (the answer to set will IMHO usually be: "create a PDF image from it").

Comment: @AdinaG: If your question is about the PGF/TikZ or the PSTricks export functionality of GeoGebra, that would probably be on-topic. Questions about creating objects within GeoGebra most likely are not. You could try asking on SuperUser.com, they have a couple of GeoGebra questions.